# Linearly independent rows in a binay matrix

Tags: algorithms, binary

I need the algorithm to finding only the linearly independent rows in a binary matrix using XOR function.

**Example 1:**

[image]

**The result:**

[image]

**Example 2:**

[image]

**The result:**

[image]

R4 is not included because:

[image]

Comment: Take a look at [this help page](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to see how MathJax works. As for the question, it is not well-defined. The second example might as well return $R_2, R_3, R_4$ because $R_1 = R_2 \oplus R_4$

Comment: You could return the lexicographically least rows found through XOR. In other words, you could make it well defined.

Answer (score 0):

If you do row reduction on $A^T$ (transpose of $A$), the columns with (row) leading $1$s will give you a maximal set of linearly independent columns of $A^T$.  The corresponding rows of $A$ would give you a maximal set of linearly independent rows of $A$.  (The reason for the transposing is that row reduction preserves column dependencies, but not row dependencies).